When was the last time a country intentionally attacked another's foreign consulate or embassy that wasn't on their soil?
In light of Israel's recent attack on the Iranian consulate in Syria (April 1, 2024), I'm wondering if this is the first case of a country engaging in hostilities by

Intentionally attacking another's foreign consulate or embassy
Outside of the aggressor's own sovereign territory

Is there precedent for this at all, or is this entirely uncharted territory?

Militias, like Hezbollah, are obviously not countries and do not have sovereign territory. Things that would be on-topic here, hypothetically, would include the United States attacking Iraq's foreign consulate in Jordan or something similar to that.
Why Exclude Proxies
For the same reason that Israel itself views a direct attack as a "severe and dangerous escalation", from IDF Spokesperson RAdm. Daniel Hagari

Iran has launched a direct attack from Iranian soil towards the state of Israel. We are closely monitoring Iranian killer drones that are on route to Israel sent by Iran. This is a severe and dangerous escalation. Our defensive and offensive capabilities are at the highest level of readiness ahead of this large scale attack from Iran.

This would not have been an escalation if Hamas or Hezbollah (both of which Israel claims are proxies) attacked Israel, as they've been doing that most every day for the past three months.
Likewise, for Israel to respond by attacking the proxy is routine. In this case, Israel is claiming it will attack Iran directly, and the justification is blunt from Foreign Minister Israel Katz,

“If Iran attacks from its own territory, Israel will respond and attack in Iran,” Katz tweets in Hebrew and Persian, tagging Iranian Supreme Leader Ali Khamenei.

So if Israel sees an attack from a proxy different from an attack by a nation-state, and I'm looking for an analogy in hisotry, I should accept Israel's own frame and find one.
This is the first time Iran has attacked Israel directly. This is an important distinction to Israel. But, is this the first time that a foreign embassy or consulate has been attacked by a remote power as Israel has done?

A list of all attacks https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_attacks_on_diplomatic_missions

As for this Q, do you include accidental attacks (if the attacker claims them so), like the US one on the Chinese embassy in Serbia?

@thegodsfromengineering no, I'm looking for a prior example to substantiate Israel's operation in Syria. If it was a mistake, clearly Iran wouldn't be looking for a military response, they'd be looking for reparations.

BTW, I suggest you change 'first time it happened' to 'last time before this occurrence'.  Ancient events are generally not on-topic here and more recent ones have more bearing on modern interstate practice.

@thegodsfromengineering good suggestion.

It would also be very hard to find a precedent for the situation being discussed here due to the many limitations.  The Iranian embassy in Syria wasn't randomly attacked because of it's status as an Iranian embassy. It was attacked at a time it was hosting a meeting of  two Iranian generals and five officers. Most countries do not have such meetings in foreign embassies during time so the comparison to would only be accurate if the question was framed as "when was the last during times of war that a country  attack other countries foreign  embassies when  military forces are stationed there"

@Schmerel feel free to ask your own questions with your own qualifications.

The Slovenian consulate in Kharkiv was reportedly destroyed during the Russian invasion of Ukraine in March 2022. I tried to find some follow-up as to how intentional but not much luck thus far. Reuters reporting at the time:

March 1 (Reuters) - The Slovenian foreign ministry said on Tuesday that the country's consulate in Ukraine was destroyed in a military attack on the city of Kharkiv.
No employees were injured in the attack, Slovenia's STA news agency cited the ministry as saying.

I'd venture a guess Russia denied it was intentional or blamed Ukraine as they did in some other incidents during the war, but I've not been able to find that, in English.
But Slovenia blamed Russia:

The foreign ministry summoned Russian Ambassador to Slovenia Timur Eyvazov on Wednesday, demanding an apology and financial compensation after a Russian missile destroyed the building housing the Slovenian consulate in Kharkiv.
The ambassador was told the destruction of civilian targets is a war crime and that Slovenia planned to notify international organisations such as the UN, OSCE, CoE and NATO of the “inadmissible act,” the foreign ministry said.


This is a really good find. The circumstances are entirely different and it may have been an accident, but I wouldn't put it past Russia to destroy a Slovenian embassy in Ukraine to send a message to Slovenia and NATO. I'm going to mark this is as accepted if nothing better is suggested in the next week.

@EvanCarroll: The current address of that consulate is in Freedom Square. Which was probably hit in this strike... which Russia then blamed on Ukraine https://www.polygraph.info/a/fact-check-russia-attack-kahrkiv-administration-building/6743301.html

The Iranians attacked the Israeli embassy in Argentina in 1992 (although, like the attack in Damascus which is attributed to Israel, they never officially took responsibility).
The Iranians did take responsibility over the attempted attack on the US consulate in Erbil (although they missed the building and their targets, and you seem adamant to ignore this incident because it doesn't play to your narrative).
The Wikipedia article has many other instances.
